# Oracle Apex Google Login HTTPS ORDS

Tags: https, oracle-apex

I'm having an issue with Oracle Apex Google authentication

It's working with http protocol but It's not with HTTPS

I have ORDS in another server pointing to the database server and Apex workspaces are working fine with https.

The issue happens when using google auth scheme to all my apps, using HTTPS.

I created a wallet with only root and intermdiate certs from the google.com website

Comment: What version of Oracle Database are you using? What is the error you're getting? What steps did you use to create the wallet - that's probably where the issue is...

Comment: @DanMcGhan Oracle database version 19c Enterprise Edition, the error when I login with google account is : " An unexpected internal application error has occurred. Please get in contact with your system administrator and provide reference# for further investigation." I created the wallet with wallet manager, and import the certs from the google page. Also did create a wallet with orapki tool and the same error is showing, Also In apex admin I copied the path to the wallet

Comment: What do you mean when you say, "It's working with http protocol but It's not with HTTPS"? Where did you make the change?

Comment: Have you read through this? http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2018/06/facebook-google-and-custom.html

Comment: @DanMcGhan I mean, I have 2 authorized URI in my google credentials, one with http and other one with https, only when I login with Google Oauth with the http works. And yes I read that post.